# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre SizedBox y Padding en Flutter?

Tags: flutter

La mayoría de ocasiones ocupo SizedBox para añadir espacios entre widgets pero recientemente encontré el widget de Padding que también sirve para añadir espacio, entonces cuál se debe usar o que ventaja tiene usar uno de los dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los 2 extienden de `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget`, pero generalmente ambos tienen distinto casos de uso.

- Cuando tienes un widget por ejemplo el de `Text` y quieres agregar más relleno para que no aparezca tan junto a los widgets cercanos entonces puedes usar `Padding` como parent, esto sería más complicado con un widget de `SizedBox`.
- Cuando quieres crear un widget de un tamaño específico le agregas como parent el `SizedBox` con las medidas determinadas.
- Cuando simplemente quieres agregar espacios separadores vertical u horizontal puedes usar cualquiera de los 2.